# TL5001 buck converter issue

Tags: pcb, pwm, buck

I have constructed the following 12v in - 3.3v out buck converter circuit using a TL5001 PWM controller based on [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvu002b/slvu002b.pdf) document. After etching PCBs and soldering surface mount components the board unfortunately does not do what I expect it to. The output voltage is measured to be about 11.6v rather than 3.3v.

Measuring the output of the TL5001, i would expect a PWM signal however there is just a constant 12v (same as the input voltage). It appears that there is no switching happening in the circuit hence no change in the output voltage. I have double checked all component values and checked for shorts. Fairly certain that the circuit I have built is exactly the same as the one I designed. Have also replaced the MOSFET driver IC, TL5001 and the MOSFET itself to no avail.

This is the first time I have done any PCB layout. I don't think my board layout was very good - the filtering capacitors for the ICs are too spaced out for example. I'm not sure if this might be the problem?

Any ideas what might be wrong?

[image: etched board]
[image: buck converter]
[image: PCB schematic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have your MOSFET incorrectly connected and the body diode is conducting all the time: -

[image]

As you can see from this TI document you have inadvertently swapped source and drain connections: -

[image]